# Как изменить на сайте фон в коде css?

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поменять код фона на сайте с голубого на оранжевый.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
body{background-color: #ff7700;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нкжно в цсс в файле, найти тег body (если это он отвечает за фон) и изменить свойство background (background-color): #ваш цвет

Answer (score 0):

Вместо black - ваш цвет, вместо body - ваш элемент.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { 
            background-color: black; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
```